# Facebook Getting picture from file server and upload it to fan page photo album

Tags: facebook

I've photos on my web server,now,i've to upload it to fan page photo album.Is there any limit for photo upload.After uploading it to fan page photo album,i've to post it to wall.

```
// Get the page access token
$accounts = $facebook->api('/my_account_id/accounts', 'GET', $params);
$data = $accounts['data'];
foreach($data as $account) {
    if( $account['id'] == $fanpage || $account['name'] == $fanpage )
        $fanpage_token = $account['access_token'];
}

// Get all albums from the page
// Must use app access token, not page token!
// You can also use a static album id to test
$fanpage_albums = $facebook->api($fanpage . '/albums', 'GET', $params);
$albums = $fanpage_albums['data'];
$sorted = array();
foreach($albums as $album) {
    if( ! strpos($album['name'], 'Special') )
        continue;
    $sorted[] = $album;
}
$album_id = $sorted[0]['id']; // Get the first one. Shouldn't be empty!

// Upload the photo (previously uploaded by user)
$args = array(
    'message' => 'Von ' . $teilnehmer_name,
    'image' => '@' . realpath($path. $_FILES['media']['name']),
    'aid' => $album_id,
    'no_story' => 1 // Nicht auf der Wall anzeigen (Thank God for that),
    'access_token' => $fanpage_token // note, we use the page token here
);

$photo = $facebook->api($album_id . '/photos', 'post', $args);
if( is_array( $photo ) && ! empty( $photo['id'] ) )
    echo 'Photo uploaded. Check it on Graph API Explorer. ID: ' . $photo['id'];
```

I tried the above code but it is not working.

Comment: try `caption` instead of message and `source` instead of `image`...also try with and without `aid` and `no_story`

Comment: add your code in a `try catch` block to actually *know* what's the error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `realpath()`, use the folder name/file name, it will work then you need a page access token.